# Spring AMQP and concurrency

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I have a “listener-container” defined like this:

```
<listener-container concurrency="1" connection-factory="connectionFactory" prefetch="10" 
            message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
            error-handler="clientErrorHandler"
            mismatched-queues-fatal="true"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit">
        <listener ref="clientHandler" method="handleMessage" queue-names="#{marketDataBroadcastQueue.name}" />          
</listener-container>
```

I want to process the messages in sequential order, so I need to set concurrency to 1.

But the bean “clientHandler” has more than one “handleMessage” methods (with diferent java classes as parameters). I can see in the application logs that messages are not processed one by one. I have several messages processed in parallel. Can it be due to having multiple methods with the same name that processes those messages?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, share DEBUG logs on the matter, including thread info.

Comment: Thank you Artem, and sorry. I have another “listener-container” defined in java configuration. Your idea pointed me to the error.

Comment: Cool! Feel free to describe the problem properly and how have you found the solution as an answer to your own question!